# Handling click co-ordinates on a scaled element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code which inserts a div tag of fixed dimensions at the point where the mouse is clicked. It is working fine.The output looks like this, after I have clicked on the center of the wrapper:

[image]

Problem is if the wrapper element is scaled, then my co-ordinates go off.  The box does not appear in the place where I click. I have included the code below:

```js
$("#wrapper").click(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  $("<div class='element' style='width:50px;height:50px'></div>").css({
    top: relY,
    left: relX
  }).appendTo("#wrapper");
});
```

```css
.element {
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {
  /* transform: scale(2);
     transform-origin: 0 0; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 200px;width: 200px;border: 1px solid navy;position: relative;">

</div>
```

How do I capture the correct mouse click coordinates of a scaled element

Comment: Correct x-coordinate is `relX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) / scale;` , `relY` using a similar formula.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks! If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it.